# PostgreSQL same name for constraint and primary key

Tags: postgresql

migrating from Oracle I'd like to reuse some definitions like:

```
ALTER TABLE CLIENTUSERS
ADD CONSTRAINT UK_CLIENTUSERS_CLIENTUS UNIQUE (CLIENTID, USERID)
USING INDEX TABLESPACE IDX
```

However this fails because clause `using index` is missing index name. Problem is that when I specify `UK_CLIENTUSERS_CLIENTUS` it fails with `[42P07] ERROR: relation "uk_clientusers_clientus" already exists`

Do I need to generate another name for constraint or is it possible to reuse the name of index like oracle do?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to use `USING INDEX` syntax you should omit column list inside `ALTER TABLE` statement:

```
CREATE TABLE CLIENTUSERS(CLIENTID INT, USERID INT);

CREATE UNIQUE INDEX UK_CLIENTUSERS_CLIENTUS ON CLIENTUSERS(CLIENTID, USERID);

ALTER TABLE CLIENTUSERS
ADD CONSTRAINT UK_CLIENTUSERS_CLIENTUS UNIQUE -- here columns were removed
USING INDEX UK_CLIENTUSERS_CLIENTUS;
```

**[db<>fiddle demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_11&fiddle=b5cf53731a3c504c464103d996c7f42b)**